# Spawned Units always move to same target regardless of setting alternate points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and i am trying to create a new game.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemyblue1script : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization

public float speed; // speed variable
public float RotSpeed = 90f;
public GameObject RocketGO; // Reference to our main character Rocket
void Start ()
{}

void Update()
{
    Vector2 Pos = new Vector2 (-10, 5);
    gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (gameObject.transform.position, Pos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    Invoke ("MoveFace", 2f);
}

void MoveFace()
{
    if( RocketGO == null)
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Rocket");
        if(go != null){
            RocketGO = go ;}
    }
    if( RocketGO == null)
        return;

    Vector3 dir = RocketGO.transform.position - gameObject.transform.position;
    dir.Normalize();

    float zAngle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.x , dir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 360;

    Quaternion desiredRot = Quaternion.Euler(0 ,0,-zAngle);
    gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(gameObject.transform.rotation , desiredRot , RotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

This is my script for Moving Enemy towards some point (using MoveTowards funtion) and rotating enemy to Players direction.   And i have one more script that is for Spawning these enemeies (Two Enemies at a time ) Script is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy1Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

//our meteorite prefab
public GameObject Enemy1blue;
public float speed;
public GameObject p1;
public GameObject p2;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{}

void SpawnEnemy1blue()
{
    //bottom left point of screen
    //Vector2 min = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector2 (0, 0));

    //top right point of screen
    //Vector2 max = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector2 (1, 1));

    GameObject Enemy1ablue = (GameObject)Instantiate (Enemy1blue);
    GameObject Enemy2ablue = (GameObject)Instantiate (Enemy1blue);
    Enemy1ablue.transform.position = new Vector2 (-11,9);
    Enemy2ablue.transform.position = new Vector2 (11,9);
}

public void startEnemy1blueSpawner()
{
    Debug.Log ("Invoked Spawning Blue Enemy");
    InvokeRepeating ("SpawnEnemy1blue",5f,30f); 
}

//function to stop spawning when game over
public void StopEnemy1blueSpawning()
{
    CancelInvoke ("SpawnEnemy1blue");
}
}
```

So now while Spawning enemies! my enemies are moving towards only one point i.e `Vector2 Pos = new Vector2 (-10, 5);` which I have defined in `Updat()` method of `Enemyblue1script`, and i want to spawn two enemies at a different positions one at `Vector2 Pos = new Vector2 (-10, 5)` (to the left side); and one at `Vector2 Pos = new Vector2 (10, 5)` (to the right side);

By using these two scripts i am able to spawn two enemies at a time, but they both move to same point, which is what i do not want to happen. I have tried stuff like in `ENEMY1SPAWNER` script > `SpawnEnemy1blue()` function i have also created two points using vector2 and i called two `Movetowards` functions there for two different enemies but is not working they are not moving.

```
    Vector2 Pos1 = new Vector2 (-10, 5);
    Vector2 Pos2 = new Vector2 (10, 5);

    GameObject Enemy1ablue = (GameObject)Instantiate (Enemy1blue);
    GameObject Enemy2ablue = (GameObject)Instantiate (Enemy1blue);
    Enemy1ablue.transform.position = new Vector2 (-11,9);
    Enemy2ablue.transform.position = new Vector2 (11,9);

    Enemy1ablue.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (Enemy1ablue.transform.position, Pos1, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    Enemy2ablue.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (Enemy2ablue.transform.position, Pos2, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly where you put this line:

```
Enemy1ablue.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
    Enemy1ablue.transform.position, Pos1, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

But if it's just in `SpawnEnemy1blue()` then it will only happen once, so the enemy will move a little closer to the target then stop.

I suggest organizing the code a little differently: add a `Vector2 target` field to `Enemyblue1script`, set it when you initialize a new enemy, and move towards it in `Enemyblue1script.Update`. Instead of creating and using `Pos`, use `target`.